# PSpice model to LTspice (SSM6L09FUTE85LF transistor)

Tags: transistors, ltspice, spice, pspice, conversion

I can't convert a specific transistor model from PSpice to LTspice. Maybe someone has ideas on how to do it?

Transistor: SSM6L09FUTE85LF Toshiba
https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Toshiba/SSM6L09FUTE85LF?qs=3kEcuH7qFhe%2FrjRbY%252BXv0A%3D%3D

PSpice model: https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=55318&prodName=SSM6L09FU

Comment: The site has a "be back soon" response. However, on [this site](https://www.heisener.com/ProductDetail/SSM6L09FUTE85LF) it shows an ECAD model. Are you sure it's PSpice and not something else? If it is PSpice then make sure it isn't encrypted -- if it is, no chance to open it up with any other program than PSpice.

Comment: The site is back up and it is indeed an unencrypted PSPICE model, so should be possible to port to LTSPICE.

Comment: Here is a guide: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/159222/help-converting-a-pspice-mosfet-lib-to-an-ltspice-sub

Comment: @JohnD No luck, again. I guess I'll never see the end of it... unless OP decides to paste the contents of the model here.

Comment: Here is the PSpice model for both FETs (N and P channels): https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/ap-en/semiconductor/product/mosfets/detail.SSM6L09FU.html

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen  I edited the question to include a direct link to the model.

Comment: @SteKulov Thanks, the other site is still "back soon". At any rate, it's a regular subcircuit, so Jarett's link should do it. I guess this is now a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

With the standard PMOS and NMOS symbols it works fine.
What exactly were you unable to do with it?

[image: schematic]
[image: pmos]
[image: nmos]